# Python: Initialize numpy arrays within an array of zeroes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, initialization

In Python, I am trying to initialize 2-element arrays of zeros within a size N by N array. The code I'm using works but I'm looking for something more efficient and elegant:

```
array1 = np.empty((N,N), dtype=object)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        array1[i,j] = np.zeros(2, dtype=np.int)
```

Thank ahead for the help

Comment: Is there any requirement why you each element should be array of 2.? Does dimension of `(N,N,2)` will work?

Comment: It as unclear what you are trying to do: to you really want an array of array (for `N=2` with your code you get `array1 = array([[array([0, 0]), array([0, 0])], [array([0, 0]), array([0, 0])]], dtype=object)`), a `3D` array (size NxNx2 for instance) or a big `2D` array (size 2Nx2N)? Maybe there would be a better solution to your code problem than what you got with this sample... Tell us more!

Comment: @Poojan, no requirement. Any array size will suffice.

Comment: @jeannej, yes a 3D array could work. But, I will need to initialize the first 2 dimensions as empty and then the third dimension as an array of zeros. Any ideas?

Comment: To give you a bit more context, I will be setting each element of an array equal to an array of size 2

Comment: @nrcjea001 Is there any reason why this will not work? `np.zeros(N,N,2)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you should probably use a 3D array:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.empty((N,N,2), dtype=object)
```

which returns an array of N rows, N columns and 2 depth. If you want to pass a (NxN) array to let's say the first depth, just use:

```
tmp = np.ones(N,N) #for instance
array1(:,:,0) = tmp
```